# How to write Unit test Cases for BehaviorSubject angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, behaviorsubject

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { User } from './user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject({} as User);
  public readonly currentUser: Observable<User> = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setCurrentUser(currentUser: User): void {
    this.currentUserSubject.next(currentUser);
  }
}
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <h1 *ngIf="username">Hello {{ username }}!</h1>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  username: string;

  private userServiceSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userServiceSubscription = this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(
      currentUser => {
        this.username = currentUser.username;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userServiceSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I have to write unit test cases in angular 9 for both service and component file can any one help me with this. I have tried different sources it is not working properly.

Spec file throwing any error with currentUser is not function while creating a createSpyObj can any give the solution for this.

Comment: Please share what you tried and what errors it throws.

Comment: It makes sense that `currentUser` is not a function because with `createSpyObj` you can only mock public methods. Try mocking it like so: `jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', {}, { currentUser: of({ username: 'abc' })});`. Also like `Philipp` said show us the test code so we know what could be wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.